# Change ws_source from lead based on last source when inserting to table Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

So, I have a function that sets ws_source based on ws_tsource. Right now I can set the right ws_source based on different ws_tsource's, example:
If ws_tsource = foobar then ws_source = foo,
if ws_tsource = foobar2 then ws_source = foo2;

But now I have to split the leads from same ws_tsource to 'foo' and 'foo2', so as they arrive one gets ws_source 'foo' and the next one gets ws_source 'foo2'.

I created a variable to check the last lead with that ws_tsource so that the new ws_source will be different, but the v_return is not affecting the If block correctly, therefore not setting the correct ws_source. So independently of the ws_source from the last lead the new ws_source is always set to 'foo2'.

What I am doing wrong here, and is it even feasible to do?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.leads_ins()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
v_return text; 
BEGIN
if NEW.ws_source IN ('foo') then
       v_priority :=  13821;

    if left(new.ws_tsource,7) = 'foobar' then

        select ws_source into v_return from leads where ws_tsource = 'foobar' order by ws_id desc limit 1;

        if v_return = 'foo' then
           v_priority :=  16460;
           update leads
           set ws_source = 'foo2',

           where ws_id = NEW.ws_id;
       end if;
      if v_return = 'foo2' then
           v_priority :=  13821;
           update leads
           set ws_source = 'foo',

           where ws_id = NEW.ws_id;
       end if;
    end if;
    end if;
END IF;

      return NEW;
end;

$function$
;
```

Answer (score 0):

So,

All I had to do was

select ws_source into v_return from leads where ws_tsource = 'foobar' order by ws_id desc limit 1 offset 1;

Because the function wasn't INSERTING a lead but UPDATING the table with the new lead already there. Without the offset the last lead was always the new lead that had by default 'foo' as 'ws_source' hence updating always to 'foo2' and never the other way around.